# tinyxml2 XMLElement constructor private?

Tags: tinyxml2

In `TinyXml` you could create an `Element` e.g. `TiXmlElement("tag")`,
but in `TinyXml2` there is no public constructor for `XMLElement`?

How do you create elements ?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the existing answer, I wrote this helper utility for my application:

```
tinyxml2::XMLElement* CChristianLifeMinistryEntry::InsertNewElement(tinyxml2::XMLDocument& rDoc, tinyxml2::XMLElement*& pParent, LPCSTR strElement, CString strValue)
{
    XMLElement *pElement = rDoc.NewElement(strElement);

    USES_CONVERSION;

    if (pElement == nullptr)
        AfxThrowMemoryException();

    pElement->SetText(CT2CA(strValue, CP_UTF8));
    pParent->InsertEndChild(pElement);

    return pElement;
}
```

It automatically adds a new child element to the end of the list. In addition, it sets the text value for the element.

Answer (score 0):

You create an element within the context of the document, so call

`tinyxml2::XMLElement * tinyxml2::XMLDocument::NewElement (const char * name)`.

E.g. to create a new element and add it as a child of an existing element `e`

```
XMLElement * new = e -> GetDocument() -> NewElement ("tag");
e -> InsertFirstChild (new);
```

Or, to do it in a single step, you could look up `append_element` in [my tinyxml2 extension](https://github.com/stanthomas/tinyxml2-ex)